# i had a list of items when iam selecting particular item it item should appear all are should dis appear in Javascript or j query give an idea

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

1. Battery
2. Car Battery Replacement
3. Service Battery/cables
4. Serpentine/Drive Belt Replacement
5. Service Battery/cables
6. xxx

when I clicked on a battery that should appear other items should disappear.

```
 function serviceid(id){
    var searchid=id;
    alert(searchid); 
     i f (searchid!=="")
     {
          if(document.getElementById("myText").value!=="")
          {
              document.getElementById("myText").value+=","+searchid;
              var x = document.getElementById('myText');
              if (x.style.display === 'none') 
              {
                x.style.display = 'block';
                  }
                      else 
                  {
                     x.style.display = 'none';
                  }
        }
        else{
             document.getElementById("myText").value+=searchid;
        }
    }   //document.getElementById("myText").value+=','+searchid;  
    else{
        document.getElementById("myText").value+=searchid;
        alert(document.getElementById("myText").value);
    }
}
```

Comment: share your full code

Comment: I am looking just selected li should remain and other should remove any idea?

Comment: remove means only selected li there and other remove permanently

Comment: other should remove permanently  (not selected one that remains only one)

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ol li').click(function() {
    $("ol li").not(this).remove();
  });
});
```

```css
ol li {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li>Battery</li>
  <li>Car Battery Replacement</li>
  <li>Service Battery/cables</li>
  <li>Serpentine/Drive Belt Replacement</li>
  <li>Service Battery/cables</li>
  <li>xxx</li>
</ol>
```

i think its helpful

Comment: I had a bunch of names in the list ,I select  one name that should be add in other div to show the list of selected names

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <ol>
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>c</li>
    </ol>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( "li" ).click(function() {
            $("li").hide();
            $( this ).show();
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a javascript solution, when you click a li element it will display it and hide the rest of the li elements.

```js
var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
Array.from(li).forEach( function(element) {
  element.addEventListener("click", function(event){
      Array.from(li).forEach(function(element){
        if(element === event.target){
          element.style.display = 'list-item';
        } else {
          element.style.display = 'none';
        }
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Battery</li>
  <li>Car Battery Replacement</li>
  <li>Service Battery/cables</li>
  <li>Serpentine/Drive Belt Replacement</li>
  <li>Service Battery/cables</li>
  <li>xxx</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest one-line solution using `index()` and `eq()`:

```js
$('ol li').on('click', function() {
  $('ol li').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
});
```

```css
ol li {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li>Battery</li>
  <li>Car Battery Replacement</li>
  <li>Service Battery/cables</li>
  <li>Serpentine/Drive Belt Replacement</li>
  <li>Service Battery/cables</li>
  <li>xxx</li>
</ol>
```